# jQuery—apply to first div of all of a particular class

Tags: jquery, selector

I have several elements with class ".MonthAccordion". I want to apply something to the first child div of every .MonthAccordion, but what I have seems to be applying it only to the first MonthAccordion's child. Subsequent MonthAccordions' children are unaffected. Where am I off?

```
$(".MonthAccordion").children("div:first").show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to make it with `find()` method, this traverse downwards along descendants of DOM elements, all the way down to the last descendant:

```js
$(".MonthAccordion").find("div:first").show();
```

```css
.MonthAccordion > * {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="MonthAccordion">
  <div>This one</div>
  <div>Not this one</div>
</div>

<div class="MonthAccordion">
  <div>This one</div>
  <div>Not this one</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although you didn't answer first, your answer works and is elegant, so I marked it as the answer and gave you a +1.

Answer (score 2):

Use the .each() method to iterate over all the elements with the 'MonthAccordion' class.

```
   $('.MonthAccordion').each(function( index ) {
      $(this).children("div:first").show();
    });
```

Comment: You answered first and your answer works, but it's less elegant. I gave you a +1.

Answer (score 2):

Just select all direct descendants, and filter by first-child

```js
$(".MonthAccordion > div:first-of-type").show();
```

```css
.MonthAccordion > * {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="MonthAccordion">
  <h4>Something else</h4>
  <div>This one</div>
  <div>Not this one</div>
</div>

<div class="MonthAccordion">
  <div>This one</div>
  <div>Not this one</div>
</div>
```

Your problem is that jQuery `first` selects **only** the **first** element in the entire collection, while `first-child` selects the first element in each parent element etc.

Comment: I was hoping it would be something this elegant, but unfortunately this gives the same result I was getting before.

Comment: It seems to work in the snippet, and the selector is just what you asked for, so if it doesn't work you're either doing something wrong, or the HTML isn't what I think it is?

Comment: I'm guessing that your code will work only if the div I'm looking for is the first child under the div. There actually happens to be an H4 prior to the div I'm trying to show.

Comment: Then you should have made it clear that you're not looking for the first child at all, but the first-of-type. I've edited the answer for future visitors, to show the correct selector

Comment: You mean like in my question where I have div:first? Not trying to be a jerk, but I believe the question was clear. I do appreciate your time, though, and your code.

Comment: Yes, I mean in your question where you write *"..I want to apply something to the first child div of every .MonthAccordion..."* ! It's not the first child, it's the first of it's type, the first child would be ... the first child, as in the first element in the parent, regardless of tagname

Comment: You contradict yourself in your own argument. You quote me as saying "the first child of every div", then say "It's not the first child..." Not only that, but in case one's English isn't very good, my code sample should've clarified any misunderstanding. How did two other people get it right if I was so unclear? That's rhetorical, by the way. I'm not waiting around for your answer.

Comment: What I'm saying is that "first child" actually means something, both in JS and CSS, where it's a specific selector. What you wanted was "first of type", which is different. The other answers work because they iterate, even `find` will iterate over the collection and then filter, which means it works in your case.